# Div containers oversized in Firefox but normal in IE

Tags: css, firefox, html

I'm using very simple external CSS sheet to setup my HTML page, but when it opens to firefox all of the div containers are bloated to twice the normal size.  Is there any easy way to fix this?
Here is the link to the CSS:

and here's the section that's bloating in the CSS:

```
/*Top header on page*/
.style1 {
    background-color:#C0C0C0;
    font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 46pt;
    height:65px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
/*Second header with phone*/
.style2 {
    background: #00245D;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 25px;
}
/*Third Header color only*/
.style3 {
    background-color:#C0C0C0;
    height: 18px;
}
/*Fourth header color only*/
.style4 {
    background-color: #ED1C24;
    height: 18px;   
}
```

Comment: Please head over to jsfiddle.net and create a fiddle before returning here and posting a link to it. Thanks.

Comment: Should I just change the height to set by % instead of pixels?

Comment: odstate please give a clear question create a fiddle with your contents and post the link here this is not much clear.... link to fiddle http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: i don't see your link css

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="defaultstyle.css" />

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6ZFVs/

Comment: the issue is that it follows the height by pixel sets in IE, but in Firefox the height of each div these control is more than 2x the size that it is in IE.